# как добавить строку содержащую измененное значение из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: mysql

подскажите,как реализовать задумку:

1. есть две абсолютно идентичные таблицы, например Table1 и Table2.
2. необходимо,чтобы при изменении любого поля Table1 в Table2 передавалась вся измененная строка(как новая запись, не update строки) из таблицы Table1.

пример:

Table1 имеет вид:

```
id  value
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

Table2 имеет вид:

```
id   value
1    a
2    b(меняем значение "b" на "z")
3    c
```

После изменений в Table2, таблица Table1 должна выглядеть так:

Table1

```
id   value
1   a
2   b
3   c
2   z
```

подскажите, как реализовать..

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_t2
AFTER UPDATE
ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO table1 (id, value) 
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.value);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ad339e4c129a006f5edcb4678867bef)

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как быть, если мы не знаем какое именно значение изменится?

Comment: @Aleksandr Вот не понял фразы, вообще.